# Function Parameter Position suddenly acting weird

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, pipeline, positional-parameter

## Code:

This example illustrates what I mean:

```
Function test{
    param(
    [parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$Param0,
    [parameter(Position = 1)]
    [ArgumentCompletions("Param1_Opt1", "Param1_Opt2")]
    [Array]$Param1 = ('Param1_Opt3', 'Param1_Opt4'),
    [switch]$NoHeader
    )
    "This is $Param0"
    "Header :$Param1"
}
```

## My issue:

For a long time I have been relying on parameter positions in all my functions today when writing a function, suddenly its stopped working the way I have been using them. The above `test` function demonstrates this issue.

If a parameter has a parameter `Position = 0` property and also has the `ValueFromPipeline`  property. When its used in pipeline. The next parameter that has a `Position` property takes its position. This also means this next parameters `ArgumenCompletions`, such as `"Param1_Opt1"` /`"Param1_Opt2"`  get suggested.

But I am not getting this behaviour at all.

```
Test "This is For Parameter Zero" "This is For Parameter One"

---- Ouput -----
This is For Parameter Zero
This is For Parameter One
```

The above works as expected, The first string is correctly assigned to `Param0` and the second to `Param1`,further more `Param1` argument suggestions works, but the following fails with an error and the pipeline string is assigned to `Param1`. Also `Param1` argument completions don't work:

```
"This is For Parameter Zero" | Test "This is For Parameter One"
---- Error ----
test: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
--- OutPut ----
This is For Parameter One
Header :Param1_Opt0 Param1_Opt0
```

---

## Desired Output:

```
Test "This is For Parameter Zero" "This is For Parameter One"

---- Ouput -----
This is For Parameter Zero
This is For Parameter One
```

The above is what I am expecting in normal usage and the following for when the pipeline is used and for `Param1` argument suggestions to work:

```
"This is For Parameter Zero" | Test "This is For Parameter One"

---- Ouput -----
This is For Parameter Zero
This is For Parameter One
```

Comment: what you want to do is simply not possible by normal means. __one of your parameters will need to be named not positional__. unless you want to explore into dynamic parameters and other awful stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment, but let me spell it out:

In your *pipeline*-based invocation, you'll need to use a *named* argument to bind to `-Param1`:

```
# Note the required use of -Param1
"This is For Parameter Zero" | Test -Param1 "This is For Parameter One"
```

The reason this is necessary is the *order* of parameter binding:

- Input provided by *arguments* is bound *first*, before execution of the command starts.
- Only *later*, when pipeline input processing begins, is parameter binding performed on *each pipeline input object*.
- As for *why* PowerShell must bind parameters this way:

  - *Arguments* passed to a command are by design evaluated *up front*, and the result of the evaluation is bound to the target parameters *once*, before the command even starts to execute.
  - *Pipeline input* is generally *not* known in advance, given that it is only produced when the input-providing command *executes*.
  - Additionally, the *data types* of the objects emitted by the input-providing command is generally *not* known, and commands are free to emit objects of *differing types*, so each emitted object may bind *differently* to the receiving command's parameters.
  - In short: There's no way to *statically, up front* determine how pipeline input will bind to parameters, so it must be deferred until runtime, and must be performed individually for each and every input object.

Therefore:

- `"This is For Parameter Zero" | Test "This is For Parameter One"` binds *argument* `"This is For Parameter One"` first, *in isolation, without considering potential pipeline input*, and, given that it is the first *positional argument*, it binds to parameter `-Param0`
- Then when pipeline-input processing starts, PowerShell tries to bind the *pipeline object* `"This is For Parameter Zero"` to a *not-yet-bound-by-arguments* parameter, and since your function's only pipeline-binding parameter, `-Param0`, is already bound, parameter binding *fails*, resulting in the error you saw.

  - Binding the argument *by parameter name* to `-Param1` avoids this problem.

Comment: I may be going crazy than, I looked at the source code for some of my modules and sure enough they have the same design but I have never used those commands in this manner before. Its all circumstantial assumptions on my end then. Thanks for this detailed clarifications. I wont be forgetting this hard lesson.

Comment: Glad to hear the explanation helped, @GaryAtlan82 - it is tempting to expect it to work the way you wanted.